# Assign a value to a variable from a prefixed list of variables

Tags: string, vba, excel, public, type-mismatch

I have a problem assigning to a variable a value from a prefixed list.
I'm going to explain better. In the "Module8" I put the following varibles with constant values:

```
Public Const Europe = 0.12, _
Middle_East= 0.12, _
Africa = 0.185
```

that should be visible also to other modules. In the "Module5" I have the following lines:

```
Sub CalcPop()

Sheets("Region").Select

Data = Range("I7:I15").Value
Geo_Region = Data(1, 1)
Population = Data(3, 1)
Extension = Data(4, 1)
S = Data(7, 1)

S = S * (1 - Geo_Region)
```

Now the code present in the "Module5" reads the Sheet called "Region" in which are present the regions (i.e. Europe, Africa, etc.) as strings, so the variable "Geo_Region" is valorized as Europe, Africa, etc.
The problem is that when it comes at the line S = S * (1 - Geo_Region), it gives me the run-time error '13' "Type Mismatch". I guess because the code read the strings in the sheet, but it is not able to associate the string to the values present in the public constants that are in the "Module8".
Could you suggest me on how to proceed in order to associate the value present in the public list with the string in the sheet?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can't assign a variable name to another variable.  Excel sees it as a string and not a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rather use a collection for that.

In Module8:

```
Dim Geo_Region_List As Collection '<-- declaring the variable as global will allow you to access it any time all over your code
```

In Workbook open method (in order to initialize the constants since the beginning of your program):

```
Set Geo_Region_List = New Collection
With Geo_Region_List
    .Add 0.12, "Europe" 
    .Add 0.12, "Middle East"
    .Add 0.185, "Africa"
End With
```

... and then, in your Module5 you access the value associated to the key:

```
S = S * (1 - Geo_Region_List(Geo_Region))
```

(I'm assuming that `Geo_Region` is a string like `Europe` and you want in return the associated value `0.12`)

Comment: Hello Matteo, thanks for the complete and detailed answer: I did as you told; I put:

    Set Geo_Region_List = New Collection
    With Geo_Region_List
     .Add 0.12, "Europe" 
     .Add 0.12, "Middle East"
     .Add 0.185, "Africa"
    End With

into  "ThisWorkbook", but now there is another problem: when I run the "Sub CalcPop()" it stucks immediately to the "Set Geo_Region_List = New Collection" line and gives me another error "Invalid outside procedure". Maybe I should put this piece of code into the Sub?

Comment: @GPace all the second block of code should be under the event "ThisWorkbook_Open", so that you initialize the collection when you open your file and keep it until the end.